# Video Color is changing After Importing It Into Adobe Premiere Pro 2022

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, premiere-pro

I captured my desktop screen using OBS Studio and when i import the captured videos into Adobe Premiere Pro 2022, their color become a little bit lighter, you can see the image i attached below, the original video is darker and the same video is imported into Premiere Pro, the color of video changes.

**Difference**
[image]

**OBS Studio Settings**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the colour profile of the footage you imported from OBS.

Make sure the colour profile of your footage matches the colour management settings in Premiere.

OBS is likely to be exporting [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) colour footage.  Premiere defaults to working in [rec.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) colour profile.

When you export from Premiere, again check which colour profile is being used.

https://blog.frame.io/2019/08/26/color-management-abobe-cc/#Premiere_Pro

Comment: I uploaded Obs studio Settings, i Think its 709.

Comment: I check marked Display Color Management option according to this blog >> https://blog.frame.io/2019/08/26/color-management-abobe-cc/#Premiere_Pro and it solved the problem for me... thank you